# Installing Cucumber with rails generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I've tried to do:

```
rails generate cucumber:install —rspec —capybara
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
Could not find generator cucumber:install.
```

I've included my Gemfile here http://pastebin.com/cDryD448 - bundle install and bundle update have both been run, as has gem update.

It's rails 3.1.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing the `gem 'cucumber-rails'` line :)